# Core Data Causing App (ViewController) To Freeze Up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, mobile

I have previously asked two questions [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467193/why-isnt-core-data-fetching-my-data/5467295#5467295) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454354/tableview-crashing-freezing-because-of-core-data-error) but there is still some problem lingering and those who helped with those questions believe there may be a problem unrelated.

When I click the tab bar item for my routineTableViewController, the app freezes up.

I am posting my data model, appDelegate, and routineViewController so I can try to get this solved once and for all.  Please let me know if there is any other information that would be beneficial.

When I click the routineViewController's tab icon, I get the SIGABRT error the in the console it shows the following:

```
2011-03-29 23:34:25.334 Curl[5817:207] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x59199e0 {metadata=<CFBasicHash 0x5918b60 [0x1013400]>{type = immutable dict, count = 6,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x5919320 [0x1013400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers"} = <CFArray 0x5919400 [0x1013400]>{type = immutable, count = 0, values = ()}
    2 : <CFString 0x5919370 [0x1013400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x5b08250 [0x1013400]>{value = +3, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    3 : <CFString 0x18d720 [0x1013400]>{contents = "NSStoreType"} = <CFString 0x18d8f0 [0x1013400]>{contents = "SQLite"}
    4 : <CFString 0x59193a0 [0x1013400]>{contents = "NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x5918e10 [0x1013400]>{value = +320, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    5 : <CFString 0x59193d0 [0x1013400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashes"} = <CFBasicHash 0x5919490 [0x1013400]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x5919420 [0x1013400]>{contents = "Routine"} = <CFData 0x5919440 [0x1013400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xf3d7cd55f214f5178953471e9f43eb0a ... 0858537b67338fb9}
}

    6 : <CFString 0x18d8b0 [0x1013400]>{contents = "NSStoreUUID"} = <CFString 0x5919120 [0x1013400]>{contents = "4C569F90-109B-4FFC-BC6A-853DF9E00B46"}
}
, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 320;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Routine = <f3d7cd55 f214f517 8953471e 9f43eb0a f785e73a 19b97ca1 0858537b 67338fb9>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "4C569F90-109B-4FFC-BC6A-853DF9E00B46";
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}
```

Data Model:
[image: Data Model]

App Delegate:

```
#import "CurlAppDelegate.h"
#import "ExcerciseNavController.h"
#import "RoutineTableViewController.h"

@implementation CurlAppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize rootController;
@synthesize excerciseNavController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext=__managedObjectContext;

@synthesize managedObjectModel=__managedObjectModel;

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator=__persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [rootController release];
    [excerciseNavController release];
    [__managedObjectContext release];
    [__managedObjectModel release];
    [__persistentStoreCoordinator release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Curl" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
    return __managedObjectModel;
}


/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Curl.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

routineViewController:

```
#import "RoutineTableViewController.h"
#import "AlertPrompt.h"
#import "Routine.h"
#import "CurlAppDelegate.h"

@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)addEvent
```

{
    CurlAppDelegate *curlAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [curlAppDelegate managedObjectContext];

```
Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSManagedObject *newRoutineEntry;
newRoutineEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    // Handle the error.
}

[eventsArray insertObject:routine atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

}

## pragma mark - View lifecycle

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
```

CurlAppDelegate *curlAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [curlAppDelegate managedObjectContext];

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.tableView setEditing: !self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        NSString *entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            [eventsArray addObject:entered];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [eventsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
         NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Freeze Up"? The app crashes? The app stay unresponsive for some time? ....?

Comment: Thanks, im updating my question with more specific details.

Comment: I added error message and console output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
```

You must have changed the model at some point. Remove the app from the device/simulator and then reload it. All should be fine after that.

Comment: This fixes the problem of the view crashing, thanks.  But the data is not saving.  When I exit the app (double click home and press minus) then reopen the app, the data is not loaded in my table view.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you remove the app from the device it erases any previous data that was saved before. This was necessary because the file was not compatible with the model in its current state. You will have to put the data in again.

Comment: Yeah I understand this.  I mean now that the app isn't crashing, it is not saving data now.  I have entered data and closed the app and the data is not there when I reopen.  I think there is some error in my code related to either the saving or fetching code.  Could you please take a look?

Comment: You should check the value of your errors when you try to save. That will tell you if anything is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @sosborn.  Do you have any more info on exactly how to do that?

Comment: In your code you are using an if statement when you save. Just add an else and then in that else statement NSLog the NSError.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is the alert view is not calling the addEvent method when text is input.  What would be the right way to implement this into the alertView method?

Comment: I added [self addEvent] to my alertView method.  Now the app is crashing before a new cell can be added to table view.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482782/cell-not-being-added-to-tableviewcontroller